# ORA-01722: invalid number - Everything seems a digit

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query:

```
WITH aux AS (
    SELECT
        col1,
        col2,
        col3
    FROM
        table1
    WHERE
        condition1
)
SELECT
    col1,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN nvl(col3, 9) != '8' THEN
                col2
        END
    ) h,
    SUM(col2) h1
FROM
    aux
GROUP BY
    col1;
```

However, when I execute it, the below error appears:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-02063: preceding line from RBIP
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number
```

But, when trying to find what was the entry in col2 that was causing issues, I get no results:

```
WITH aux AS (
    SELECT
        col2
    FROM
        table1
    WHERE
        condition
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    aux
WHERE
    NOT REGEXP_LIKE ( col2,
                      '[[:digit:]]' );
```

Aby hints on how to keep searching for the col2 culprit will be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression is not going to find mixed digits and non-digits:

```
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE ( col2, '[[:digit:]]' );
```

That is `'AAA1AAA'` will match because it has a digit.

Try checking that everything is a digit:

```
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE ( col2, '^[[:digit:]]*$' );
```

Or that there are no non-digits:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE ( col2, '[^[:digit:]]' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you use this command: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve019.htm#SQPUG040
and post its results.

Obviously, it is a **type casting** issue, but to be sure, table definition is needed.